# Visual Studio "Replace in Files" function stuck searching backwards?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

As title. When using the "Replace in Files" function ( default Ctrl+Shift+H ), the search starts at the bottom of my file and works its way upward. In the bottom left it says "Find (x), **Backwards**, Current Document". How do I kick VS12 to not search backwards?

Comment: I see the same thing in VS2013 https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/details/1055118

Comment: For those seeing this issue, I'd love to hear whether you still see it if you start Visual Studio with no extensions loaded (devenv /safemode from a Visual Studio Command Prompt). Please reply here or on the Connect bug that Legalize has posted above. Thanks!

Comment: Same thing happened to me in VS2017. Can't make it to search forward

Answer (score 0):

To the right of the "Search term" textbox at the top of the "Quick Replace" window, you may see an arrow pointing to the left.  If you hover over it, a tooltip should appear that reads "Find Previous (Shift+F3)".  Clicking the small down-arrow to the right of that and choosing "Find next" should fix this problem.